# I like learning new things but hate to do revision

Tags: motivation, methodology, learning

This problem has been troubling me for some years. The fact that I'm actually very curious in person about everything, I naturally become a learner who likes studying a lot.

However, I also get so-so memory at the same time. I still can remember things if I do at least 1 revision. However, I find myself hate revision. And whenever I find myself forgetting things, I become demotivated. Even I took detailed notes, I just don't motivated to read again my notes for some reason. Revision seems like a daunting task to me.

I can devote hours and hours sitting in front of my desk reading up new things and studying. However, I hate to come back to the materials/same things I read before. This creates a dillema: if I don't go back to it, I forget about it next time.

As we all know, revision needs to be done in a timely manner. It usually takes me 10-14 days before I eventually convinced myself to do the revision. But that's not how study works, I guess.

**Thus, what should I do to motivate myself to do the revision I should have done? Or actually it's not about motivation, but something goes wrong that I don't notice? What are the possible causes for the phenomenon?**

p.s. at school it's still better as there're exams to push me reviewing the materials. However, now I'm already a working adult, thus I need to identify ways to help me overcome this bad habit as what I have now is just self-study.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. I think this question is probably out of the scope of the community.

Comment: @Pikachu피카츄, then so is this too? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27581/improve-learning-skills

Comment: That post was posted a really long time ago. Many types of posts that used to be appropriate on the site are now considered off-topic.

Comment: The linked question should have been closed years ago: "How do I learn?" is far too broad, and far too individualized, for anyone to give a definitive answer to. That's the main thing about this site -- we don't want Reddit-style discussions or anecdotes; we want authoritative answers. So, I have hammered the linked question closed. I suspect this question has a similar problem, but I'll leave it for the community to decide.

Comment: I you forget about it, you haven't learned it. If you like learning new things, then that might be a motivating factor - you need to not forget about it in order to learn it.

Comment: update the question in more details to solicit more feedbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motivation comes from need. If you need to know something in the future then make a note of that fact and, just perhaps, your motivation for properly learning it will increase. That *need* could be internal or externally driven. When very young your teachers force you to learn the multiplication tables, perhaps. Or you want to excel at something in life, so your need is internal.

But humans don't learn from brief exposure to an idea unless it is extremely dramatic (a bear coming through the door). You need reinforcement to get the brain to rewire itself and retain what you study.

See [this post about the *Hipster PDA*](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/1168/1293) on another site here for one way to drive reinforcement in a mostly painless way.

If you want to know the background of brain science and learning see *The Art of Changing the Brain* by James E Zull.

Comment: I'm glad eventually there's a helping hand. Thank you professor!